# How to create a specific number of arrays with a single command?

Tags: ruby

I want a way to make multiple arrays at the same time, given a specific number or command. I'm specifically trying to make a pyramid with a number of arrays based on base.length, and I feel like there should be a way to make base.length number of arrays. I don't want to write multiple lines of code, I specifically want to write a method equivalent to English sentence: "make X number of empty arrays."

Comment: Is there any code that you can add to your post to show what you've already tried?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with

```
Array.new(x) { [] }
```

for example `x = 4`:

```
Array.new(4) { [] }
#=> [[], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Vishnu, if you write `a = Array.new(4) {[]} #=> [[], [], [], []]`, then `a.first << 1`, you obtain `a #=> [[1], [], [], []]`, as desired. A common mistake is to write `e = []; a = Array.new(4, e)` (same as `Array.new(4, [])`). Then `a.first << 1` results in `a #=> [[1], [1], [1], [1]]`. That's because `e.object_id #=> 49867270664000` and `a.map(&:object_id) #=> [49867270664000, 49867270664000, 49867270664000, 49867270664000]`. Note you could also write (less desirable, imo) `4.times.map { [] }`.